# Drupal 6 Ahah With FileField Problem

Tags: ajax

i'm creating a form which uses ahah in Drupal 6.

I have 2 select fields. The first uses ahah in order to populate the second and it works well.

But the problem is when I add a file field to the form because the ahah call doesn't work (it doesn't appear in firebug and the page is refreshed instead of the normal behavior). If I remove the file field it works again.

Any idea please? I'm getting frustrated thinking about the solution.

Thanks

Comment: I experimented on it, file upload element appears and flash outs immediately. So strage :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common issue that is reported [here](http://drupal.org/node/399676) and even in the drupal [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/331941), the issue is reported so I think it's not yet solved at all so you need to find another solution that AHAH for the file upload filed.